# U-boot scripting : How can I check if a variable exists in u-boot?

Tags: shell, u-boot

In a u-boot script, I'm trying to write a simple script that checks if a variable exists such as :

```sh
if test -z $var; then
    setenv var 1;
fi
saveenv
```

So that on next boots, the variable `var` does not get set again.

It seems that u-boot script are responding to a Hush shell syntax but I can't find a way to do this as if you would do this in a regular shell.

Anyone has an idea on how to do this ? Or another idea to replicate this behavior ?

Thanks

Comment: This script is the way to do it. The only reason that it is not working, is that you have to add double quotes around $var (if test -z "$var"). This is a bit tricky, since this is not required for the test -n. Reason for this is that if $var is indeed empty, the resulting command is "if test -z", without a value to test for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use option `-n` of test command:

```
if test -n "$var"; then
    setenv var 1;
fi
saveenv
```

See also this answer from Wolfgang Denk, original creator of U-Boot:

https://lists.denx.de/pipermail/u-boot/2005-August/011446.html

Comment: `-n` will tell you if the variable is set, not if it's unset

Answer (score 2):

Finally I found a solution.

Instead of using `test`, I'm using `printenv` to test if the variable exists.

Example :

```sh
if printenv var; then echo found; else echo not found; setenv var 1; fi
saveenv
```

This will print `not found` the first time, but will print `found` afterwards. The trick was to use `printenv`'s return value.

Comment: This works, but outputs an error for whatever variable you are testing if it doesn't exist (`## Error: "var" not defined`).  In the case of the u-boot that I'm using I was able to use a slight variation on the test approach (and this did not give an error): `if test -z "${var}"; then echo "empty"; else echo "set"; fi` (I understand this didn't work for the original poster)